# When using the free() function in aix ( static area free())

Tags: c, aix

I am not good at English, so please understand me.

If you look at the code below, you can free() the static area, but it didn't die. On Linux, of course, they die, but not on AIX( Test machine 7.1).

I'd like to know why.
And what kind of memory did the free()?

```
#include <stdio.h>

char testbuf[512];
void main()
{
        char *p=NULL;
        p = testbuf;
        printf("before local:%llx static:%llx\n", p, testbuf);
        free(p);
        printf("after free local:%llx static:%llx\n", p, testbuf);
        printf("No Die.!\n");
}
```

Compilation

> gcc -maix64 -o 1 1.c

Result

> before local:1100014b8 static:1100014b8
>   after free local:1100014b8 static:1100014b8
>   No Die.!

Comment: You didn't dynamically allocate memory via malloc/calloc etc. why do you want to free the global array?

Comment: Freeing memory that has not been allocated via `malloc` and friends results in _undefined behaviour_ (google that), which includes "programs dies" and "apparently working fine"

Comment: @Trickzter : It is a simple example of a mistake in code. I didn't know that the program didn't die, but I found out after looking at the code.

Comment: @Jabberwocky : **Undefined results occur** if the Pointer parameter is not an address that has previously been allocated by the malloc subsystem, or if the Pointer parameter has already been deallocated. (from IBM : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/m_bostechref/malloc.html#malloc__free)
"Undefined results occur" ->  Can other memory in the Heap area be removed?

Comment: @Jabberwocky : Sorry..If I change the question, can I just assume that nothing happens because the static areas are still there?

Comment: @HyungKyuShin no you can't. It's _undefined behaviour_. In th best case your program will crash, in the worst case the program will continue but internal data structures used by `malloc` and `free` might get damaged which may lead to strange bugs later in your program.